# Stochastic stability

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, risk-assessment

In [this book](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9781852337612) (p. 37, 43, 44) the notion of *stochastic stability* of a stochastic process is defined by the condition
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \|x_k\|^2\right] < \infty.\tag{1}
$$
It is shown that for Markovian switching systems of the form $x_{k+1} = f_{\theta_k}(x_k)$ driven by a finite Markov chain $(\theta_k)_k$, stochastic stability is equivalent to mean-square stability.

Let us replace the above expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ by a [coherent risk measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure) $r$ leading to the condition
$$
r \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \|x_k\|^2\right] < \infty\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

We know that $r \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \|x_k\|^2\right] \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r(\|x_k\|^2)$ (subadditivity property), therefore, if $r(\|x_k\|^2)$ converges adequately fast so that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r(\|x_k\|^2)$ is finite, then \eqref{2} will hold. I am, however, interested in the converse: under what additional conditions does \eqref{2} imply that $r(\|x_k\|^2)\to 0$?

A first step would be to see whether this holds for the essential supremum; if $\mathrm{esssup} \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \|x_k\|^2\right] < \infty$ is it true that $\mathrm{esssup}(\|x_k\|^2)\to 0$?

Comment: You forgot to put the link for the book

Comment: @Hamed thanks for pointing this out. I added the link.